# How to do a screenshot for android?

Tags: android, screenshot

I'm trying to do a presentation of my android app, and I realise that there's no key combination to do a screenshot. After some online researching, I found that to be able to do a screenshot with an android phone, the device should be rooted.

Is there any other way to do screenshot on android without having the phone rooted?

Thank you.

The device is an HTC Inspire 4G.

Comment: Do you mean using code, or just when using the device? Most of android phones, will make a screenshot at volume down + power button. But a few phones have other implementations of taking a screenshot, just google for it.

Comment: what's your device manufacturer & device model

Comment: Which device are you using??Y because it differs among devices..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about taking a screenshot on a phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Eclipse, switch to `DDMS` perspective, select your device in `Devices` view and press button `Screen capture`.

[image]

**No root required.**

Answer (score 1):

Usually you press the power and the volume down button at the same time but it could be different for your device

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it programatically, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661536/how-to-programatically-take-a-screenshot-on-android) is what you need. Good luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

On Samsung Galaxy Phones/Tabs there are gestures to do that.

You can either use hand and swipe horizontally over display or (for Note devices) use SPen.

[image: Swipe horizonally with your hand]
[image: Swipe horizonally with your hand]
[image: Press and hold with SPen button]

See Settings for gestures that apply to your device (and check that they are enabled).